# How to restore GRUB in my case?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub

I have 2 NVMe in my system, let's call them OldDrive and SecondaryDrive.
OldDrive had Windows installed, and SecondaryDrive had various Linux distributions installed.

I replaced OldDrive with NewDrive and installed a fresh Windows, so now the PC boots directly to Windows as expected.

Although Linux was installed on SecondaryDrive, it seems like GRUB sits on OldDrive and is therefore now gone.

GRUB is linked to Kubuntu if I remember correctly.

The BIOS no longer sees it, it does offer me to boot to Kali though (one of the other distributions I installed).

I still have access to OldDrive, so I can install it on a spare PCIe and can boot to Kubuntu from it if needed.

What would be the best way to restore GRUB? (Preferably with whatever settings and wallpaper it had, although that's not too big a deal to redo)

Comment: Did you every have any linux partitions on "OldDrive" or was it just grub installed there *(in the shared EFI partition)*?

Comment: only GRUB was installed there (I don't even know/remember why), I made sure that OldDrive only had Windows partitions, and SecondaryDrive had all the Linux partitions

Comment: Okay, that mens you won't have to migrate `/boot` as well then.

Answer (score 0):

On modern systems (using UEFI) grub is installed in pieces in two places:

- An EFI "stub" on your EFI partition
- Modules and configuration in a /boot directory.

Typically you use [`grub-install`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/grub-install.8.html) to install grub and [`update-grub`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/update-grub.8.html) to configure it.

Since you say you can still boot into your system the easiest thing to do would be mount your EFI partition on NewDrive to somewhere.  To find your EFI partition you can use commands: `sudo lsblk` and `sudo blkid` to give you some information about available partitions.

Let's say your EFI partition is `/dev/sde5`, then run:

```shell
mount /dev/sde5 /mnt
grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/boot
umount /mnt
```

This should be enough to both install the EFI grub stub, and inform your UEFI firmware about it.

Then make sure to update the file `/etc/fstab`.  This should contain an entry for `/boot/efi`.  You'll need to change that so it mounts your EFI partition from NewDrive instead of OldDrive.  Try to use the PARTUUID of that partition if you can you can.  Again `sudo blkid` will give you the PARTUUID.  The entry should end up looking something like this:

```
PARTUUID=be5da649-024d-4799-ac09-394d9d8b1a03 /boot/efi vfat defaults  0       1
```

---

I've deliberately skipped explaining how to migrate `/boot` itself since, you say all your linux partitions are on the same drive.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I am not really a Linux expert. Is your solution suggesting that I plug OldDrive, boot to Kubuntu from it, and then execute the commands you listed?

Comment: @Annathema Yes, make sure to replace `/dev/sde5` with your own EFI partition. You'll need NewDrive attached as well by the time you execute the commands. (I assume that's possible).

Comment: yes, I can add a 3rd NVMe via a PCIe expansion card, so that's not a problem. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: is there a simpler way? for example, once I boot into Kubuntu, unplug OldDrive (not sure if it's ok to do it on a running system) and do a grub-install (which has a GUI if I remember correctly)